# Problem with access in directories

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, kubuntu, kde

I am using Kubuntu alongside Windows 10. I've done it by shrinking a free space and installing the Kubuntu on it. Now I want to use commands like `cd` on Windows' partitions but it doesn't work and the partitions appear like devices like in the following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is little bit confusing. i think you are looking for this

if you cant open your windows partition then simply disable fastboot in your windows 10. go to control panel select **power option**. the in right **select Choose what the power buttons do**. Then click  **Change settings that are currently unavailable** and enter password if needed. uncheck **Turn on fast startup**. after that you can mount your windows drive in your kubuntu installation.

if you can mount your windows system then use `cd /media/<user username>` instead of `cd MEDIA`

Comment: sorry for confusing but you get right , thanks  it works